# Adding DRM to existing HLS

Tags: nginx, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, drm

For the project I am currently working on, I have an encoding server that converts mp4 files into HLS playlists using ffmpeg. Segments and m3u8 files are then copied to a storage server and served over nginx with load balancing, on demand.

Requirement put in front of me is to implement screenshot protection. Googling around, as one does, I found out that it is actually possible if I add DRM protection to my video content.

However, what I was unable to find out myself is how:

1. Is DRM something that I can do on my own or do I need to buy DRM keys somewhere? Is third party DRM provider a requirement or just makes things easier?
2. Can I add DRM protection to already created HLS playlists? Or will I need to re-encode everything? I found few tutorials using bento4 with DRM but they are mostly done by DRM providers so they explain how to integrate DRM with their service. Can I run DRM using my infrastructure and keys, without third party service? Should I?

If someone can point me in the right direction, it would be most beneficial. For example how to convert simple mp4 file into hls that when played in Safari on iOS cannot be screenshot.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In theory you could build your own DRM but in practice you most likely want to use one of the three major ones as they are integrated into browsers and devices, and for screen shot prevention in particular, will have existing integrations into device's secure media path, if the device/browser supports this, to prevent screenshots (although none of them can prevent someone taking a shot of the screen with a separate camera or device).

You can either work directly with the DMR providers Google Widevine, Apple FairPlay or Microsoft PlayReady or, possibly more easily, at least initially, you can get multi DRM service from a third party multi DRM provider.

You can definitely add DRM to existing HLS playlist without re-encoding, but you do have to do the encryption which usually means re-packaging.

You can experiment with open source packagers like Shaka Packager to see what works best for you: https://shaka-project.github.io/shaka-packager/html/tutorials/drm.html

This includes a test widevine credential that you can use: https://shaka-project.github.io/shaka-packager/html/tutorials/widevine.html#widevine-test-credential